# JavaScript 'dataTable' function is not working in react environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use javaScript's dataTable plug-in in react environment but when I am trying to implement it's syntax-

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
       data: dataSet,
       columns: [
           { title: "Name" },
           { title: "Position" },
           { title: "Office" },
           { title: "Extn." },
           { title: "Start date" },
           { title: "Salary" }
       ]
   } );
```

inside componentDidMount() method.

```
    componentDidMount() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
            data: dataSet,
            columns: [
                { title: "Name" },
                { title: "Position" },
                { title: "Office" },
                { title: "Extn." },
                { title: "Start date" },
                { title: "Salary" }
            ]
        } );
    }
```

Facing following error:

```
{TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_12__(...).dataTable is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable` is not a JS method, but a jQuery plugin: https://datatables.net/manual/api. So to use it, you'd need to install it first, together with jQuery.